# CSS change active select for radio

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using the following to create a toggle switch instead of radio buttons - it works great

```
.switch
{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    padding: 2px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.switch input[type=radio]
{
    display: none;
}

.switch label
{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 3px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #aaa;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.switch label:hover
{
    text-shadow: 0 0 2px #fff;
    color: #888;
}

.switch label.checked 
{
    background: #8fc800;
    color: #eee;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #8fc800, #438c00);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #8fc800, #438c00);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #8fc800, #438c00);
    cursor: default;
}
```

And html:

```
<div class="switch">
    <input type="radio" name="weekly_new" id="weekSW-0" <?=$yes_checked?> value="Yes" />
    <label for="weekSW-0" id="yes">ON</label>
    <input type="radio" name="weekly_new" id="weekSW-1" <?=$no_checked?> value="No" />
    <label for="weekSW-1" id="no">OFF</label>
</div>
```

And jquery:

```
<script>
     $(".switch label:not(.checked)").click(function(){
        var label = $(this);
        var input = $('#' + label.attr('for'));

        if (!input.prop('checked')){
            label.closest('.switch').find("label").removeClass('checked');                        
            label.addClass('checked');
            input.prop('checked', true);
        }
    });

    $(".switch input[checked=checked]").each(function(){
        $("label[for=" + $(this).attr('id') + "]").addClass('checked');
    });
    </script>
```

As you can see the label.checked gives the button it's 'look' - what I want to do is have a different color for when No is selected as opposed to yes - red for no, green for yes, groundbreaking huh?

Anyway, cannot for the life of me figure out if it can be done

I assigned IDs to the labels and tried e.g.

```
.switch label.checked #yes { blah blah }
```

But this rendered the style useless!

As I've done the code this way, can this be done?

I've created a fiddle if easier to fiddle with... obv had to put valuse checked=checked as I normally load from mysql table but it cannot

http://jsfiddle.net/aS69U/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This CSS should work with your code:

```
.switch #no.checked {
    background:red;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/aS69U/3/)**

---

Cool customization by the way ;-)